# How to send email with flutter?

Tags: email, flutter

I tried all packages to send email ( flutter_email_sender  - flutter_mailer -url_launcher), copy and paste the example, but always the same  error message : " MissingPluginException(No implementation found for methode ...), I serach a simple example to send email on press button.

thank you

Comment: try deleting the build folder and rebuild again

Comment: Did you re-build the app? Hot reload doesn't work when installing a plugin which depends on native code.

Comment: seems to be that, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
To use latest version of url_launcher or above version of 4.1.0+1
 , you have to migrate to android x.

 [https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/androidx-compatibility][1]
```

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

        class SendEmail extends StatelessWidget {


    void _contact() async {
        final url = 'mailto:dude@gmail.com';
        if (await canLaunch(url)) {
          await launch(url);
        } else {
          throw 'Could not launch $url';
        }
      }

          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            return RaisedButton(
            onPressed: (){_contact()},
            child: Text('Mail'),
          ),
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding these lines on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
<queries>
  <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="sms" />
  </intent>
  <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="tel" />
  </intent>
</queries>
```

then run flutter clean, then build again
it work for me but this is specific for url_launcher